# Search deep in array and delete

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got the following array:

```
var arr = [
    {
        1: {
            id: 1,
            title: 'test'
        },
        children: [
            {
                1: {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'test2'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The objects directly in the array are the groups. The 1: is the first language, 2: is second etc. The id is stored in every language object (due to the database I'm using). The children array is built the same way as the 'arr' array.

Example of multiple children:

```
var arr = [
    {
        1: {
            id: 1,
            title: 'test'
        },
        children: [
            {
                1: {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'test2'
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        1: {
                            id: 3,
                            title: 'test3',
                        },
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Now I need to delete items from this array. You can have unlimited children (I mean, children can have children who can have children etc.). I have a function which needs an ID parameter sent. My idea is to get the right object where the ID of language 1 is the id parameter. I got this:

```
function deleteFromArray(id)
{   
    var recursiveFunction = function (array)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            var item = array[i];

            if (item && Number(item[1].ID) === id)
            {
                delete item;
            }
            else if (item && Number(item[1].ID) !== id)
            {
                recursiveFunction(item.children);
            }
        }
    };

    recursiveFunction(arr);
}
```

However, I'm deleting the local variable item except for the item in the array. I don't know how I would fix this problem. I've been looking all over the internet but haven't found anything.

Comment: how would this array/json look like with multiple children?

Comment: did you try `splice` though?

Comment: @gurvinder372 added in main code.

Comment: @Siddharth no, because of the multiple children.

Comment: @NinaScholz Read where I explained how my array is built. There I explain the whole array what everything is.

Comment: I would first transform this object into something more readable something  like `{1:[{2:[], 3:[]}]}` first.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{ 1: { id: 1, title: 'test' }, children: [{ 1: { id: 2, title: 'test2' }, children: [{ 1: { id: 3, title: 'test3', }, children: [] }] }] }];

function deleteFromArray(id) {   
    function recursiveFunction(arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var item = arr[i];
            if (item && Number(item[1].id) === id) {
                arr.splice(i, 1);
            } else if (item && Number(item[1].id) !== id) {
                item.children && recursiveFunction(item.children);
            }
        }       
    };

    recursiveFunction(arr);
};

deleteFromArray(2);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7mv5h4j/2/

`deleteFromArray(2)` will make `children` empty and `deleteFromArray(1)` will make `arr` empty itself.

Comment: I'm just dumb. I just noticed in my original array children isn't an array but an object. I thought it was an array so I made the question with the example array where children is an array too. You know if in inspector console it's possible to output the string of an array variable?

Comment: @JoshuaBakker do you mean `JSON.stringify()`?

Answer (score 0):

This proposal features a function for recursive call and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the iteration and short circuit if the `id` is found. Then the array is with [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) spliced.

```js
var arr = [{ 1: { id: 1, title: 'test' }, children: [{ 1: { id: 2, title: 'test2' }, children: [{ 1: { id: 3, title: 'test3', }, children: [] }] }] }];

function splice(array, id) {
    return array.some(function (a, i) {
        if (a['1'].id === id) {
            array.splice(i, 1)
            return true;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            return splice(a.children, id);
        }
    });
}

splice(arr, 2);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```